# How to modify VHDL counter code and convert vector to integer correctly?

Tags: vhdl, counter

We are supposed to modify a code in VHDL for counter we got from school by a line or two to count in the range from A to B. This is what we've got so far.

```
entity counter is
generic (
    B : integer := 4; 
    A : integer := 0
 );
port (
 CLK : IN  std_logic;
 RST : IN  std_logic;
 Q   : OUT std_logic_vector(log2(N)-1 downto 0)
);
end cntn;

architecture run01 of counter is 
signal a0 : std_logic_vector(Q'range) := (others => '0');
begin
Q <= a0;
citac: process (RST, CLK)
begin
  if RST='1' then
     a0 <= (others => std_logic_vector(conv_integer(A, cnt'length)));
  elsif rising_edge(CLK) then 
     a0 <= a0 + 1; 
       if a0 = A then 
           a0 <= (others => '0'); 
       end if;
     end if; 
  end process;
end architecture;
```

So far we've added this piece of code

```
a0 <= (others => std_logic_vector(conv_integer(A, cnt'length)));
```

But there seems to be problem with the conversion. Is there anyone that knows how to solve this issue? I'm pretty much new to VHDL, so I'm having a little bit hard time at this one.

Comment: Use `ieee.numeric_std.all` package. Then just write `a0 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(A,a0'length));`

Comment: Wow, thank you, it seems to be working!!!

Comment: @Juergen That looks awfully like an answer to me...

Comment: code's not complete. What is `N`? What is `log2`? Where are your libraries?

Comment: This code won't even analyze (even adding in the missing context clause. `end ctn;` does not match the entity name (`counter`). There's also not a declaration for `cnt` used in the problem assignment statement. The aggregate `(others => std_logic_vector(conv_integer(A, cnt'length)))` attempts to assign an integer value (the length of the mythical cnt) to each element of `a0` illegally type converted to std_logic_vector, when the element base type of `a0` is std_ulogic. As far as the accepted answer, it's curious as to why you'd assign the binary length of `a0` to `a0`.

Comment: There also isn't an `N` declared (used in specifying the range of `Q`, noticed while searching for a `log2` function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ieee.numeric_std.all` package. Then just write

```
a0 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(A,a0'length));
```

Comment: If you're suggesting to use `numeric_std`, you could also suggest that `a0` could as well be an `unsigned` type...

Comment: @JHBonarius That's not a reason to downvote a correct answer.

Comment: Btw. I could suggest many things, but OP was asking for a fix to exactly one line of her source code.

Comment: That I place a comment, does not mean I downvoted the answer.